# Setando o Focus() em TextBox do UserControl

Tags: c#, winforms

Tenho o seguinte UserControl :

```
public partial class SliderChrome : UserControl
{
    private int _min;

    public int Min
    {
        get { return _min; }
        set
        {
            txtmin.Text = _min.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Utilizo esse UserControl no Form da seguinte maneira:

```
public partial class MacroForm : Form
{
    private void ValorMinEMaxParametros(bool isEnglish, int Min, int Max)
    {
        DialogResult dialogResult;
        if (isEnglish)
        {
            dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Do you...", "Max ...", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
        }
        else
        {
            dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Deseja...", "Max ...", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
        }

        if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            sliderChrome1.Min = Min;
            sliderChrome1.Max = Max;                
        }
        else if (dialogResult == DialogResult.No)
        {
            sliderChrome1.Min = 0;
            sliderChrome1.Max = 1;
            sliderChrome1.txtMin.Focus(); //Erro
        }
    }
}
```

Gostaria de setar o Focus no TextBox txtmin do UserControl. Como faço ?

Comment: Ao invés de `sliderChrome1.txtMin.Focus();`, se você fizer `sliderChrome1.txtMin.Select();` também não funciona?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tive que fazer da seguinte maneira:

Criei o método `setFocus()` no meu `UserControl` que seta o focus no componente desejado.

```
public partial class SliderChrome : UserControl
{
    private int _min;

    public int Min
    {
        get { return _min; }
        set
        {
            txtmin.Text = _min.ToString();
        }
    }

    public void setFocus()
    {
        txtmin.Focus();
    }
}
```

E no Form seto o focus através do método `setFocus()`

```
public partial class MacroForm : Form
{
    private void ValorMinEMaxParametros(bool isEnglish, int Min, int Max)
    {
        DialogResult dialogResult;
        if (isEnglish)
        {
            dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Do you...", "Max ...", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
        }
        else
        {
            dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Deseja...", "Max ...", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
        }

        if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            sliderChrome1.Min = Min;
            sliderChrome1.Max = Max;                
        }
        else if (dialogResult == DialogResult.No)
        {
            sliderChrome1.Min = 0;
            sliderChrome1.Max = 1;
            sliderChrome1.setFocus(); //Setando o focus atráves do método
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Olha meu comentário na pergunta, por favor

Answer (score 0):

Dentro da classe `MacroForm`, você pode adicionar o evento `Form.Activated` e chamar o método `Focus()` do controle:

```
private void MacroForm_Activated(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    txtMin.Focus();
}
```

Outra opção que pode funcionar é alterar o `TabIndex` do TextBox `txtMin`. Essa propriedade define a ordem que os controles receberão o foco, do menor para o maior.

Answer (score -2):

Seja mas explicito, o que é que vc realmente pretendes fazer? Se for o que eu intendi, então tenta fazer assim :

```
                 txtMin.Focus();
```

Comment: Use a opção de comentários quando não pretender elaborar uma resposta!